# Win 32 program to verify a issuer whether it has issued from trusted root CA or not?

Tags: windows, winapi

Win 32 program to verify a issuer whether it has issued from trusted root CA or not? Right now Iam using WinVerifyTrust API, Instead of that any other APIs are there?? Pls Help me out